# How to determine which keys are locked lock with Hazelcast Imap

Tags: hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast Imap interface to lock items in a distributed way.Instead of putting item in map I just call lock method which seem to be working but I don't know how to query which items are locked currently since items are not available in the map.Is there a way to query hazelcast about locked keys?
Here is the example code:
    public void testMap_DistributedLock() {
        final Config hazelcastConfig = new Config();
        int numberOfRecords = 100;

```
    final HazelcastInstance instance1 = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig);
    //monitorCluster(instance1);

    IMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = instance1.getMap("myMap");
    System.err.println("starting lock");
    int index  = 0;
    while(index<numberOfRecords){
         myMap.lock(index++);
    }
    System.err.println("After locking index is: " +index);
    System.err.println("myMap.size()=" + myMap.size());
}
```

and output is :

```
starting lock
After locking index is: 100
myMap.size()=0
```

PS:Using java7 with Hazelcast 3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API like IMap::getLocks but you can iterate through all known locks using IMap::isLocked and collect keys that are still being locked. If you really want some getLocks method please go ahead and file a feature request on github.